# Restore site database to previously used database using myphp

Tags: database, wordpress, restore

I had been optimizing my site manually with the wp optimize plugin. In the database tab in this plugin, I  accidently deleted a table from my database before losing complete access to my site.

Now I can't access it from any platform, including the admin dashboard. Im not sure what table was deleted. This was the only database table deleted though. I did however get a backup of the database before it was deleted.

I initially ran the suggested tips to try to debug this problem. I uninstalled the plugin jetpack from my site so I could attempt to reconnect it. Now I can not access a settings or profile page, nothing. to my site.

I then, tried to access my site through the easywp dashboard by accessing my database and files through myphp although I do not know how to restore back to a previously used database to reset my site back to before this database was deleted.

**This is the email i recieved to help retrieve my site.**

The links given to temporarily access site will not even work either.

If your site appears broken and you can't access your dashboard normally, WordPress now has a special "recovery mode". This lets you safely login to your dashboard and investigate further.

https://myrebeldiaries.com/wp-login.php?action=enter_recovery_mode....

To keep your site safe, this link will expire in 1 day. Don't worry about that, though: a new link will be emailed to you if the error occurs again after it expires.

When seeking help with this issue, you may be asked for some of the following information:
WordPress version 5.5.3
Current theme: Clean Journal (version 2.6)
Current plugin:  (version )
PHP version 7.4.9

## ****Error Details

**

### An error of type E_COMPILE_ERROR was caused in line 90 of the file /var/www/wptbox/wp-content/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/capsman-enhanced.php. Error message: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/wptbox/wp-content/plugins/capability-manager-enhanced/includes/functions-admin.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') https://db-comporellon.easywp.com/index.php?server=4

---

This is the information to myphp dashp=board for referencing on which would be the prefered method to fix this critical error.

URL: https://db-comporellon.easywp.com/db_structure.php?server=4&db=417145_9d83e2450364fda2af51389349186203

This message is displayed on myphp admin page

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage has been deactivated. Find out why.

I attempted to add the backed up database to myphpadmin and this is the error i recieved:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0000.001 (0) Opened log file at time: Tue, 17 Nov 2020 10:11:49 +0000 on https:/' at line 1

Server: mysql-cluster-3-mysql-master.database.svc.cluster.local:3306 via TCP/IP
Server type: Percona Server
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.7.26-29-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 29, Revision 11ad961
Protocol version: 10
User: myrebeldiaries-73ce30@10.232.17.104
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

Web server
Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.1
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.4.1

Comment: I removed the phpMyAdmin tag, but if it's relevant then please explain how.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.